# using C# solution for Listview label

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to use this solution to convert URLs to link in a listview label.

```
private string ConvertUrlsToLinks(string text)
{
   string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~_-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return r.Replace(text, "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"Open in a new window or tab\" target=\"&#95;blank\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");
}
```

I have tried this in the listview databound but its not working.

```
  protected void ProjectRecentActiviyListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label ProjectPostLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ProjectPostLabel");

        ProjectPostLabel = ConvertUrlsToLinks({0});
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You're function returns a string. You can't assign that to a label. You could go ProjectPostLabel.Text = ... but I'm not sure that's going to do what you expect (turn it into an anchor). Where does MVC come in?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are using ASP.NET Web Forms, not MVC.

1. You must use your `ProjectPostLabel` instance with `Text` property - no need to create a new label that is not assign to anywhere.
2. From your event you must retrieve Url property, not the label control. I have used  `NorthwindEmployee` class with `URL` property in my ListView. You must cast it to your own class that is used in the list view.

   ```
   protected void ProjectRecentActiviyListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
   {
       ProjectPostLabel.Text = ConvertUrlsToLinks(((NorthwindEmployee)e.Item.DataItem).URL);
   }
   ```

And you must remember that only the last item from your list view will be displayed in the label (unless you expect that behavior). If you want to list of URLs from the list you can write this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectPostLabel.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    protected void ProjectRecentActiviyListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectPostLabel.Text += string.Format("{0}<br/>", ConvertUrlsToLinks(((NorthwindEmployee)e.Item.DataItem).URL));
    }
```